# Alternative to AVFoundation captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation

I created an app that uses `AVFoundation` `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` to take a picture every 0.2 seconds and analyse the picture. However, I didn't realize that it made the shutter sound every time it took a picture until I had already built the app.

**Question:** Is there a good alternative to `AVFoundation` `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` that doesn't make a shutter sound or is there a legit way to turn the sound off?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution to take photo would be `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate` method `capturePhoto(with:delegate:)`. Check out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturephotooutput) for `AVCapturePhotoOutput`.

But as i can see from your question, you want to mute the shutter speed when taking photos. As per apple documentation API, there is no way you can mute the shutter sound when taking photo. Until unless user turn off the mute hardware button.

As a workaround you can start analysing the camera frame of a continuous video by using `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`. Here is the detailed documentation from apple for [How to capture video frames from the camera as images using AV Foundation on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1702/_index.html). With this method you can still get the images and avoid shutter sound as well.